# the mechanics of let! in computation expressions

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I am currently working on the computation expression series of the fabulous  fsharpforfunandprofit website and I have a question regarding the lesson 4 "wrapped type" of the computation series.  I have tried reading a bit further , but there's an important notion I am not grasping.

Actually, I do understand the definition of bind :

```
member Bind : M<'T> * ('T -> M<'U>) -> M<'U>
```

but one thing I do not understand at this point is the magic when using it in a computation expression  with let!:

For instance in :

```
let product'' = 
    dbresult {
        let! custId = getCustomerId "Alice"
        let! orderId = getLastOrderForCustomer "" // error!
        let! productId = getLastProductForOrder orderId 
        printfn "Product is %s" productId
        return productId
        }
printfn "%A" product''
```

**getCustomerId "Alice"** give me back **M<'T>** , but **custId**  is already the **unwrapped 'T** and I cannot see anywhere how does this magic trick work...

Is it part of the code hidden in the let! instruction within Fsharp core assemblies?  Could someone explain to me how the let! get the T' out of its wrapper?

Thanks for your explanations

Comment: this is exactly what `Bind` is used for (unwrapping): you can think of `let! custId = ...` as just `Bind (getCustomerId "Alice") (fun custId -> ... the next line(s))` so each `let!` will get you another level of `Bind`

Comment: `let!` itself is *syntactic-sugar*  that *desugars*  to bind - you can find some details in this [post from Don](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/09/22/some-details-on-f-computation-expressions-aka-monadic-or-workflow-syntax.aspx)

Comment: want me to wrap it into an answer? ... one moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this:

```
let product'' = 
    dbresult {
        let! custId = getCustomerId "Alice"
        let! orderId = getLastOrderForCustomer "" // error!
        let! productId = getLastProductForOrder orderId 
        printfn "Product is %s" productId
        return productId
        }
```

will *desugar* to something like (naming the monad type as just `DB<'t>`):

```
let product'' = 
   DB.Delay(fun () ->
       DB.Bind(getCustomerId "Alice",(fun custId ->
          DB.Bind(getLastOrderForCustomer "",(fun orderId ->
             DB.Bind(getLastProductForOrder orderId, (fun productId ->
                printfn "Product is %s" productId
                DB.Return productId)))))))
```

so basically you get a `Bind` level for each `let!` (you can usually ignore the `Delay`)

As you can see the *computational expression* syntax is much nicer than the nested `Binds` - most languages which supports monadic expressions of some sort have similar *syntactic sugar* - even C# (`from ... in ... select` aka LINQ)

Comment: The thing I forgot was what the bind method bind(m,f) was actually doing. When matching m  it applies f  to a and thus unwrap the value for future use. Thanks you very much.